# How can I install Cinder to Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-studio-2013, libraries, cinder

So I the other day I wanted to create a game in C++. I have a fair amount of knowledge with c++. I wanted to use CinderBox for my libraries for the OpenGL. However i don't know how to install libraries in Visual Studio. I am using Visual Studio 2013.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have downloaded cinder, look in the tools folder. There will be a program called 'TinderBox' that can generate a Visual Studio project for you with the correct libraries.